# How to use java.util.Vector as return type

Tags: java, vector

I'm novice in Java and i got a problem. How to use java.util.Vector; as return type of a function?

```
import java.util.Vector;
...                      
public Vector func( Vector v )
{
    System.out.print(v[0]); // as example
    // and i got an error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Vector.
}
```

If i'm using it like this

```
// got an error: Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ReferenceType
public Vector <double> func (Vector <double> v)
{
    System.out.print(v[0]);
}
```

In C++ it looks like this:

```
#inlcude <vector>

std::vector <double> func( std::vector <double> v )
{
    std::cout << v[0]; // as example
}
```

Comment: Java's is its own language. Don't base your knowledge of it off of C++.

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Vector`. From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) _If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector_. Further, don't use rawtypes.

Comment: I need to write a function, which return type is an array with unknown (at the start of function) size. But i have no practice in Java...

Comment: You can use a method of Vector to get an object at an offset. Also, I think Vector is depricated.

Comment: Then you go and practice by reading documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Note that the problem here has nothing to do with the return type. The line `System.out.println(v[0]);` isn't a return statement - you'd still have the same problem if you changed your return type to `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this on non-array Objects in Java:

```
v[0]
```

Only an `array` can be dereferenced through the `[]` notation. A `Vector` is its own object with its own methods to get/manipulate data.

Your return type of `Vector` is correct, so your question is a bit misleading.

See here for the `Javadocs` on Vector: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

Of particular importance (and as mentioned by @Boris the Spider: `...Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.`